# (AHK) How to simulate Shift behaviour with LAlt and RAlt held together

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, autohotkey

The title has it. Shift is too far away to reach for making a letter capital; want to use these two ALTs instead. Here is one of my numerous attempts:

```
If GetKeyState("LAlt") & GetKeyState("RAlt")
    send {Shift Down}
else
    send {Shift Up}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do read https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm, specially the beginning. Hotkeys start with a `::` and end with a `return`.

In your case, you are looking for a remapping: Please look into https://autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm.

For guidance, but not tested:
You could probably do something like

```
<!>!Alt::Shift
```

Comment: Does not work. What happens is alts are pressed _down_ and when I press some other symbol, say 't', instead of 'T', I get no output. No capital letter appearing.